# Python 3: Replace a character in a list based on indices

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, char

New Python Developer: trying to build the initial part of a hangman game. I had trouble replacing elements in a list based on determined indices.

```
    word = ["kangaroo"]  # word the player needs to guess
    word_taken_out = word[0]  # convert to string
    
    hint_list = []  # initialize empty list that will be populated with question marks based on the length of the word the player needs to guess
    
    
    def populate_hint_list(hint_list):  # function to populate hint_list w/ appropriate number of question marks
        for indexes in word_splitted:
            hint_list.append("?")
        return hint_list
    
    
    def split_list(word): # function to convert the word the player will guess into a character list
        return [char for char in word_taken_out]
    
    
    word_splitted = split_list(word_taken_out) # call function and store in variable for character list
    
    hint_list = populate_hint_list(hint_list) # call function to populate the hint list with question marks
    print("The word the player will need to guess:", word[0])
    print("The Hint List:", hint_list)
    
    user_guess = input("Enter a letter: ") #prompt user to enter a letter
    
    user_guess_list = [] # initialize empty kist that will store the user's guess in a list
    user_guess_list.append(user_guess) # store the user's guess in a list
    print(user_guess_list)
    
    found_indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(word_splitted) if x == user_guess] # find index occurances where the user's guessed letter matches in the word
    print(found_indices)
    
    # insert in hint_list the user_guess based on the found indices; in other words replace the question marks in the hint_list 
    # based on the found indices that matched with the users guessed character
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, why create a list with a word in it, then immediately take out that word. Why not just assign the string in the first place?

```
word = "kangaroo"
```

Next, you can create a list with all question marks of the appropriate length much easier than your function.

This code will make a list with one "?" in it, then the `*` operator duplicates and concatenates that list the desired number of times, here the length of the string, being the number of letters in the word.

```
hint_list = ["?"] * len(word)
```

Your list comprehension does split the word into a list as you want, but this can more easily be achieved by simply casting the string to a list

```
chars = list(word)
```

Lastly, you've correctly identified the index(es) of correct guesses, so now you just need to replace the "?" with the letter in the hint_list using the index(es)

```
for i in found_indices:
    hint_list[i] = user_guess
```

This should do what you want.

```
word = "kangaroo"
print("The word the player will need to guess:", word)

hint_list = ["?"] * len(word)
print("The Hint List:", hint_list)

chars = list(word)
print("The correct characters:", chars)

user_guess_list = []  # initialize empty kist that will store the user's guess in a list

while "".join(hint_list) != word:  # loop until the game is complete
    user_guess = input("\nEnter a letter: ")  # prompt user to enter a letter

    user_guess_list.append(user_guess)  # store the user's guess in a list

    found_indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(chars) if
                     x == user_guess]  # find index occurances where the user's guessed letter matches in the word
    print("Guess found at indices:", found_indices)

    for i in found_indices:
        hint_list[i] = user_guess

    print("\nAll guesses so far:", user_guess_list)
    print("Current hint list:", hint_list)

print("\nYou did it! The word is ", word)
```

Output

```
The word the player will need to guess: kangaroo
The Hint List: ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?']
The correct characters: ['k', 'a', 'n', 'g', 'a', 'r', 'o', 'o']

Enter a letter: a
Guess found at indices: [1, 4]

All guesses so far: ['a']
Current hint list: ['?', 'a', '?', '?', 'a', '?', '?', '?']

Enter a letter: b
Guess found at indices: []

All guesses so far: ['a', 'b']
Current hint list: ['?', 'a', '?', '?', 'a', '?', '?', '?']

Enter a letter: c
Guess found at indices: []

All guesses so far: ['a', 'b', 'c']
Current hint list: ['?', 'a', '?', '?', 'a', '?', '?', '?']

Enter a letter: d
Guess found at indices: []

All guesses so far: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
Current hint list: ['?', 'a', '?', '?', 'a', '?', '?', '?']

Enter a letter: e
Guess found at indices: []

All guesses so far: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
Current hint list: ['?', 'a', '?', '?', 'a', '?', '?', '?']

Enter a letter: f
Guess found at indices: []

All guesses so far: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
Current hint list: ['?', 'a', '?', '?', 'a', '?', '?', '?']

Enter a letter: g
Guess found at indices: [3]

All guesses so far: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
Current hint list: ['?', 'a', '?', 'g', 'a', '?', '?', '?']

Enter a letter: h
Guess found at indices: []

All guesses so far: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
Current hint list: ['?', 'a', '?', 'g', 'a', '?', '?', '?']

Enter a letter: i
Guess found at indices: []

All guesses so far: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
Current hint list: ['?', 'a', '?', 'g', 'a', '?', '?', '?']

Enter a letter: j
Guess found at indices: []

All guesses so far: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
Current hint list: ['?', 'a', '?', 'g', 'a', '?', '?', '?']

Enter a letter: k
Guess found at indices: [0]

All guesses so far: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k']
Current hint list: ['k', 'a', '?', 'g', 'a', '?', '?', '?']

Enter a letter: n
Guess found at indices: [2]

All guesses so far: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'n']
Current hint list: ['k', 'a', 'n', 'g', 'a', '?', '?', '?']

Enter a letter: r
Guess found at indices: [5]

All guesses so far: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'n', 'r']
Current hint list: ['k', 'a', 'n', 'g', 'a', 'r', '?', '?']

Enter a letter: o
Guess found at indices: [6, 7]

All guesses so far: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'n', 'r', 'o']
Current hint list: ['k', 'a', 'n', 'g', 'a', 'r', 'o', 'o']

You did it! The word is  kangaroo
```